# Does a get request call actually run the controller action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, controller, request

I have a really simple use case in Rails - hitting an endpoint `/users/show/:id` will update that user's status to `'accepted'` and show their application to them.

## The Controller Spec

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def show
    User.find(params[:id]).update_all(status: 'pending')
    @some_variable = 'blahblah'
  end
end
```

## The Test

```
require "spec_helper"

RSpec.describe UsersController do
  describe "GET show" do
    it "should set user to accepted status" do
      get :show, { id: 1, foo: 'bar' }
      expect(User.find(1).status).to eq('accepted')
    end
  end
end
```

## Question

The above fails for me, which tells me that the controller code to update the status is never actually running.

Does `get()` actually hit the route **and run the controller action**, or does it just make a mock request? I tried putting a few `puts` statements in the controller and didn't see them output, which leads me to further believe that the controller logic is never getting called.

If it's the latter, how can I actually call my controller action?

Thanks!

Comment: Is the test failing simply because the user's status is not accepted, or is there an error somewhere?

Comment: I edited my post, but it feels like the controller action itself is never getting called. Adding some `puts` statements in the controller, or even a `binding.pry` doesn't seem to work, because those statements never execute.

Comment: `update_all(status: 'pending')`, if i'm right, u r updating the status to 'pending'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it does. To illustrate you can simplify your controller as so:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def show
  end
end
```

And test it like so:

```
describe "GET show" do
    it "should return 200 status" do
      get :show, { id: 1, foo: 'bar' }
      expect(response.status).to eq(200)
    end
end
```

For your reference:  https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/controller-specs

Comment: thanks. I realized from your comment that I hadn't authenticated and my request was producing a `302` redirect to get me to sign in.

Comment: Glad I could help - albeit indirectly. :)

Answer (score 1):

I doubt, your show action should be like this,

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def show
    User.find(params[:id]).update_all({stauts: 'approved'},{ status: 'pending'})
    @some_variable = 'blahblah'
  end
end
```